# SQL: lookup values from a table with multiple conditions to return final calculation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to build a query that calculates final revenue based off a number of conditions that affect the cost of items bought from multiple stores over a period of time. Each store/item/location has difference costs.

Currently I have scheduled, partitioned tables showing sales per store that update how many apples/pears I buy each day. This feeds into a table that looks like Table B below. Currently the costs are manually updated in the query as cost per item, per store. However it hasn't been accounting for differences in cities or delivery fees, so total costs will be inaccurate.

As there are so many cost variations it seemed easier to update a central table with different costs breakdowns. For example Table A contains the list of items and cost per items at different stores, cities and if delivery has cost us money.

Rather than manually update one long query with lots of conditional statements per store, Can I have one query that matches the costs just from Table A whenever it is updated?

Thanks

**Table A:**

| Item | Store | City | Costper item | Delivery | Delivery fee per item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | SnakMarket | Townville | $1 | y | $0.5 |
| Pears | SnakMarket | Townville | $3 | y | $0.5 |
| Apples | SnakMarket | Cityshire | $1.50 | n | $0.0 |
| Pears | SnakMarket | Cityshire | $3.50 | n | $0.0 |
| Apples | DollarFood | Townville | $2 | y | $0.75 |
| Pears | DollarFood | Townville | $4 | y | $0.75 |
| Apples | DollarFood | Cityshire | $3 | n | $0.0 |
| Pears | DollarFood | Cityshire | $4 | n | $0.0 |

Table B should have the outputs that groups the costs similarly to below.

**Table B:**

| Item | Quantity | Total Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 350 | $xxxx |
| Pears | 601 | $xxxx |

Comment: Can you show what is your expected output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RiccoD... thanks for getting back. I've updated the above which should hopefully give you more context.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't displayed your quantities table which would be helpful, but from my understanding, it looks something like this:

| Date | Item | Store | City | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/09/29 | Pear | SnakMarket | Townville | 69420 |
| 2022/09/29 | Apple | SnakMarket | Townville | 42069 |
| 2022/09/29 | Pear | SnakMarket | Cityshire | 10000 |
| 2022/09/29 | Apple | SnakMarket | Cityshire | 45454 |

... etc

If your table looks something like the above (irrespective of column order), you can perform a LEFT JOIN to add the costings per item

```
SELECT
A.Date,
A.Item,
A.Store,
A.City,
A.Quantity,
B.Costperitem,
B.Delivery,
B.Deliveryfee
FROM
`Quantity Table` AS A
LEFT JOIN
`Table 1` AS B
ON
A.Item = B.Item
AND
A.Store = B.Store
AND
A.City = B.City
```

This will combine your data and you will end up with and output like:

| Date | Item | Store | City | Quantity | Costperitem | Delivery | Deliveryfee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/09/29 | Pear | SnakMarket | Townville | 69420 | 3 | y | 0.5 |
| 2022/09/29 | Apple | SnakMarket | Townville | 42069 | 1 | y | 0.5 |
| 2022/09/29 | Pear | SnakMarket | Cityshire | 10000 | 3.5 | n | 0 |
| 2022/09/29 | Apple | SnakMarket | Cityshire | 45454 | 1.5 | n | 0 |

... etc

From this, you should be able to work out your groupings to get the total revenue generated.

Comment: Thanks @jeremy. Table B would actually be the expected output with the grouped fields. There would be store quantity tables with purchase data -say Table C (SnakMarket)+ Table D (Dollarfood) that would match up with the costs per item variant in Table A. Does that make sense? Thanks,